# Strange behaviour in ASP.NET MVC: removing item from a list in a nested structure always removes the last item

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

**Scenario**

I have a parent/child model (to be exact a small questionnaire form and a one or more number of contacts). For historic reasons, all of this would have been done on the same form so user would have a form for the parent and one child and they would hit a button to add more children. Child has a few standard fields and the same with the parent, nothing fancy. Main requirement is that the data must not touch the database until all is valid and setup while I would have to go back to server for adding deleting children.

**Implementation**

It was very quick to get this working in ASP.NET MVC (using **MVC 2 with VS 2010**). I got two models, one for parent and one for the child and got only one controller. Controller has a `Create` Method which is a `get` and gets a default view with a fresh brand new parent containing one child. I use **editor template** for the child model which works nicely.

I have one HTML form which has a "save" and "add child" and I have "delete" button for each form. Since this cannot be stored in database, I store the temp model in the form itself and it goes back and forth between browser and server. Perfromance is not much of an issue here but the cost of development since there are quite a few of these forms - so please do not get distracted too much by suggesting an alternative approach although I appreciate comments anyway.

In order to find out which child to delete, I create temp GUID Ids and associate them with the child. This will go onto the HTML input's value for delete button (usual trick when you have multiple actions and the same form).

I have disabled caching.

**Issue**

Please have a look at the snippets below. I have debugged the code and I have seen always correct GUID being passed, correct item removed from the list in the controller and correct items being rendered in the template. BUT ALWAYS THE LAST ONE GETS DELETED!! I usually click the first delete and can see that the last gets deleted. I carry on and first item is the last being deleted.

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        EntryForm1 entryForm1 = new EntryForm1();
        entryForm1.Children.Add(new Child("FILL ME", "FILL ME"){ TempId = Guid.NewGuid()});
        return View("EntryForm1View", entryForm1);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(EntryForm1 form1, FormCollection collection, string add)
    {
        if (add == "add")
            form1.Children.Add(new Child("FILL ME", "FILL ME") {TempId = Guid.NewGuid()});

        var deletes = collection.AllKeys.Where(s => s.StartsWith("delete_"));
        collection.Clear();
        if (deletes.Count() > 0)
        {
            string delete = deletes.FirstOrDefault();
            delete = delete.Replace("delete_", "");
            Guid g = Guid.Parse(delete);
            var Children = form1.Children.Where(x => x.TempId == g).ToArray();
            foreach (Child child in Children)
            {
                form1.Children.Remove(child);
            }               
            // HERE CORRECT ITEM IS DELETED, BELIEVE ME!!
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Redirect("/");
        }
        return View("EntryForm1View", form1);
    }
```

**View snippet**

```
    <% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Children.Count;i++ )
  {%>
        <h4> <%: Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Children[i])%></h4>

        <%
  }%>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" name="add" />
            <input type="submit" value="add" name="add" />
        </p>
```

**Child Editor template snippet**

```
        <%: Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.TempId) %>
        </span>
        <input type="submit" name='delete_<%: Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.TempId) %>' value="Delete" />
```

**Many thanks for your time and attention**

---

**UPDATE**

I was asked for model classes and I am sharing them as exactly as they are.
`Entryform1` is the **parent** and `Somesing` is the **child**.

public class Somesing
    {

```
    public Somesing()
    {

    }

    public Somesing(string o, string a) : this()
    {
        OneSing = o;
        AnozerSing = a;
    }

    [StringLength(2)]
    public string OneSing { get; set; }

    [StringLength(2)]
    public string AnozerSing { get; set; }

    public Guid TempId { get; set; }

}

public class EntryForm1
{

    public EntryForm1()
    {
        Sings = new List<Somesing>();
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public List<Somesing> Sings { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: in the child editor template snippet you have two variables: x and m. where are these coming from?

Comment: It does not matter what I named them. Name (x, m, ...) is only valid inside the expression bracket.

Comment: Whats doing in the EntryForm and it's Children(exactly what type of collection is Children), can you post that info?

Comment: See my update. Nothing fancy in the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, as Ahmad pointed out, `ModelState` is the key to the issue. It contains the collection as such:

- FirstName
- LastName
- ...
- Sings[0].OneSing
- Sings[0].AnozerSing
- Sings[1].OneSing
- Sings[1].AnozerSing
- Sings[2].OneSing
- Sings[2].AnozerSing

Now if I delete item 0 from the list, now the items will move up in the list and the data in the ModelState will go out of sync with the model. I had expected ASP.NET MVC to be clever enough to find out and re-order, but well that is asking for too much.

I actually implemented PRG (post-redirect-get) and by keeping the model in session, I was able to display correct information but again, **this will remove all the validation in the collection and if model itself is valid, it will happily save and redirect back to home "/".** Clearly this is not acceptable.

So **one solution** is to remove all items in the `ModelState` and then add a new entry for the model itself (with key of `EmptyString`). This can actually work alright if you populate it with error "Item deleted" as this will be displayed in the validation summary.

**Another solution** is to manually change the items in the model state and re-arrange them based on the new indexes. This is not easy but possible.

Comment: What often happens for me if I delete say Sings[0], then I end up with a gap, and none of the subsequent items get bound.

One solution I've found partially helpful is that you can declare all the Indexes, and if you do such then it doesn't get stuck on the gap, but instead loads every index you've informed it about.  So, then for Every "Sing" entry you'd have a line explicitly telling the binder about yet another index of Sing ( So, you could have a loop and output something like the following pattern: <input type="hidden" name="Sings.Index" value="0" /> )

Answer (score 9):

I believe that problem lies with ModelState. When the view gets rendered, which I assume is where the issue lies, after the `POST`, the last value is not displayed i.e. removed from the view.

The issue is that `Model.Children.Count` will return the correct number of elements to display.

Lets break this down...

So if you have initially had 5 then removed the first one which is at index 0 based on the Guid, you now have items 4 items left with indexes 1 to 4.

However, when rendering the view after the post, the HtmlHelpers do not look at the values in model posted, but rather the values contained within the ModelState. So in the ModelState, item with index 0 still exists and since the loop is now looping to 4, the last element will not be displayed.

The solution, use `ModelState.Clear()`

Comment: Would I not lose all my validation by doing that??

Comment: @aliistad - not sure, you could try ` if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {   ModelState.Clear(); 
            return Redirect("/");
        }
        return View("EntryForm1View", form1);`. In any case, I would suggest using Post-Redirect-Get approach.

Answer (score 3):

***ModelState.Clear()*** will Solved this problem.

ModelState.Clear() is used to clear errors but it is also used to force the MVC engine to rebuild the model to be passed to your View.