# Editing collections and disabling form persistance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there anyway to disable MVC "refilling" from form data for a particular request?

I'm developing an MVC sample that edits a "shopping cart", which contains of a simple list of items and their quantities. So far, so typical.

I'm using editor templates so that I can use `EditorFor` on the list of items and MVC will generate the `Items[x]` field prefix and provide me with basically free model binding on the post back.

Part of the sample is to remove items with a quantity of zero between posts. Unfortunately, since the HTML helper methods prioritise form values over model values, this is resulting in the *number* of items being reduced but the *form data* of the previous item that was posted at that position. Non-posted data for the row obviously remains correct.

NB. I realise that one would usually utilise the PRG pattern here, but since this is a sample there is no persistance layer (I'm relying on form data + a static product repository implementation).

**Edit:** To be clear I'm not arguing against the PRG pattern, the sample is simply highlighting model binders and server side validation.

Comment: The PRG pattern is not only about persistence - it is about respecting the way the web works. Without implementing the PRG pattern, if a user uses the "back" button to return to a form, all data will be re-posted again. Remember, the postback anti-pattern is utterly broken.

Comment: @Richard there is no 'postback' in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @George - there is a POST method in HTTP. I am well aware that ASP.NET MVC does not have a PostBack property on Page, possibly because it doesn't have a Page class.

Comment: @rsenna - I'm aware of why the PRG pattern should be used. The sample is for internal training as a way of teaching the specifics of ASP.NET MVC to multi-platform developers who are already generally profficient.

Comment: @Richard POST != PostBack. Using one where you mean the other is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @George - semantics that only apply to ASP.NET. The browser is "posting back" the data to the web server. However, to avoid future misinterpretation, I've updated the original question.

Comment: @George Stocker: I understand postback as meaning "a HTTP POST to the same page that the form is on" (that's the definition found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postback)). This is required by the WebForms model; and this *may* also be used in ASP.NET MVC: one just has to use the same HTTP form action for both post and presentation. Many people still do that; and what I'm trying to say here is that this is not a very smart thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it seems to be the problem I encountered: [Strange behaviour in ASP.NET MVC: removing item from a list in a nested structure always removes the last item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438904/strange-behaviour-in-asp-net-mvc-removing-item-from-a-list-in-a-nested-structure)

The solution I found was to clear the ModelState and then populate with what you need.

Also PRG is possible, you have to store the model and modelstate temporarily in the session and on the GET, retrieve from session and remove. This is exactly what [ASP NET MVC Contrib 2](https://github.com/mvccontrib/MvcContrib/commit/135411386b6817def9aaa493493ff582788ba377) was doing in `ActionFilter PassParametersDuringRedirect`.

Comment: I didn't know about ModelState.Clear(), thanks. Good point about session state, though I was trying to avoid it.

Comment: I do not like using session but there does not seem to be an alternative. MVC contrib also use it. If you find a better way please let me know.

Comment: I mean that I'm trying to avoid using it for the sake of the demo (which also has no database).