# MVC post collection as model without ordered index

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, collections

Say I have these class

```
public class Parent
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    int Name { get; set; }
    List<Child> child { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    int Name { get; set; }
}
```

If I want to send unordered list I can put in the View

`<input id="Parent_Index" name="Parent.Index" type="hidden" value="@x">`

But what if my collection has another collection.

```
public class Parent
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    int Name { get; set; }
    List<Child> child { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    int Name { get; set; }
    List<GrandChild> grandChild { get; set; }
}

public class GrandChild
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    int Name { get; set; }
}
```

How do I send unordered `GrandChild` to controller? I'm just confused what kind of naming I should use in the View.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: is there a reason youre handwriting the html instead of using html helpers like `@Html.DisplayFor`, `Html.EditorFor`, etc? If you using html helpers, you don't need to be aware of the syntax. Or is this because youre trying to post back ALL of this information (parent + children + grandchildren) in a form submit ?

Comment: @GregH: Correct, I need to POST all of the information back to controller during submit.

Comment: gotcha. In that case, you could write a couple loops iterating through the children and grandchildren, use html helpers to produce inputs for the grandchildren and then inspect the html. that should show you the format that mvc is expecting and should be pretty quick to do. Personally, I tend to avoid this use case and use ajax to post specific pieces of data instead of the whole thing at once- tends to make life much easier

Comment: @GregH: this is what I got from the renderer `<input type="hidden" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="Child_0__GrandChild_0__ID" name="Child[0].GrandChild[0].ID" value="1">` 

So, what's the correct format for the `Index`?

Comment: I don't see any field called `Index` in your models.. here the 0 following `Child` is the index of the child and the 0 following `GrandChild` is the index of the grandchild. Not  too sure what you mean. something like this assuming you have 2 loops with counters `i` and `j` iterating through children and grandchildren: `<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="Child_[@i]__GrandChild_[@j]__ID" name="Child[@i].GrandChil[@j].ID" value="1">`

Comment: @GregH: This is basically what I'm looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45133856/mvc-collection-missing-items-on-post 

But I'm confused about the naming for Index if my collection has another collection in it.

Comment: are you able to add and remove items from the list of `Child` and `Grandchild` on your view? If not, there's no reason to even use the code in the post you've linked. Also, an alternative to using that is to use a script that goes through your inputs and renames them to the expected mvc naming conventions if an input is added or removed from a collection